# Non-graphical tty's not stretching full screensize

Tags: linux, console

on tty7 (graphical environment) nothing's wrong, I can enjoy the whole pixels of my screen which is the main thing.

But here's something a bit annoying, when I switch on terminals from 1 to 6, the visual space is shrunk to get into the upper left corner of my screen leaving the rest unused.

worth a million words :
[image: <img>pretty boring</img>]

*How can I fix that ?*

**update :** here's an shot of my screen
[image]

Comment: OS? Boot loader, GRUB, GRUB2 other?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13617/in-linux-console-no-x-how-to-stretch-console-screen-to-fit-monitor

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem when using a laptop with an external display that had a higher native resolution than the laptop's built-in screen. The external display was running on its native resolution, but the tty only extended to an area matching the laptop's built-in screen.

I was able to solve this issue by issuing

```
fbset -a -g 1920 1080 1920 1080 32
```

The two instances of 1920 and 1080 match the 1920x1080 resolution of the external display. The 32 at the end is the color depth and I took this value from the output of `fbset -i` that I ran *before* the command above to investigate the current settings.

On modern Debian based distros with nvidia probably another way is to [edit `/etc/default/grub`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/206931).

Furthermore, you can increase font size on HiDPI displays with

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup  # Suggested Terminus, 16x32
sudo systemctl restart console-setup.service  # To apply immediately to all TTYs
```

Comment: In my case on Ubuntu 16.04 just installing [fbset package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/fbset) overwrites (asking first)  `/etc/fb.modes` (originally created by [Retropie](https://retropie.org.uk/docs/Debian/)) and after reboot start working fullscreen, no need of `fbset --all --geometry`.

Answer (score 1):

Only throwing out some suggestions. Install `hwinfo` and run:

```
  su -c 'hwinfo --framebuffer'
  # Or
  sudo hwinfo --framebuffer

  ...
  Mode 0x0343: 1400x1050 (+1408), 8 bits
  Mode 0x0345: 1400x1050 (+2816), 16 bits
  Mode 0x0346: 1400x1050 (+5632), 24 bits
  ...
```

Or use `vbeinfo` if you are in GRUB cli environment.

Update kernel entry in GRUB by

```
kernel /boot/vmlinuz ... vga=0x0346
```

Or in

/etc/default/grub

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=2560x1440x24
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep
# And / or perhaps
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="vga=0x038f"
```

Where x24 is `bits` from `hwinfo` aka depth - not needed, but...

http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/Simple-configuration.html#Simple-configuration

```
# Can also try to use res instead of keep
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=2560x1440
```

If it does not work then perhaps add `vga=0x0abc` to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT
```

Using proprietary nVidia drivers you might have to install `v86d` and add video option to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`. Something in the lines of `video=uvesafb:mode_option ...`

You might also want to look at `setupcon -f` for font by configuration file perhaps at `cat /etc/default/console-setup`. `man setupcon`

Comment: thanks for your answer but it's not about the GRUB, the GRUB is fine. I was meaning when Ubuntu (in my case) starts, the graphical user interface is loaded on the tty7, but when I switch on another tty (non graphical) the problem occurs, see my post update, I've uploaded my screen.

Comment: @Oddant: Your system tries to load the best resolution etc. for consoles. You can use GRUB to modify this. E.g. increase resolution etc. GRUB uses it own gfxterm and can be nice as flowers or whiskey and your graphical environment be a mess. Same goes for console. Console uses either VGA [text mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_mode) or [frame buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_framebuffer). What could be the case is that an invalid mode is used for console. Hence configure GRUB. *And run `update-grub`.* (Which is a stub for `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`)

Comment: @Oddant: As you have not stated which boot loader you use nor any other information like GPU or OS it is hard to give any more help.

Comment: thanks, my boot loader is the GNU GRUB version 1.99-21utbuntu3.1.
I tried what you adviced me but nothing is changing

Comment: I had to add the new entries you told me in the /etc/default/grub as there were not specified originally.

Comment: And you ran `update-grub` before boot? What does `hwinfo --framebuffer` give you?

Answer (score 1):

- find out the resolution your monitor can do (eg. 1280x800):

  on grub screen, type <kbd>C</kbd>, then enter `vbeinfo`:

  `grub> vbeinfo`
- add to `/etc/default/grub`

  ```
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"
  GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=1280x800
  ```
- update grub

  ```
  update-grub
  ```

Comment: This is the only solution that did it for me. Note that it needs to be `GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX` despite what the default `grub` file suggests (`#GRUB_GFXMODE`).